# Android - weird gradient image appearing, due to cache?

Tags: android, android-layout

Some of us are seeing a weird gradient in our buttons when publishing from our machines.  Its a blue circle with black corners. Someone told me it might be due to some sort of caching issue, however I don't know how to get rid of it.

The same code build on someone elses machine removes this issue.

I've already deleted the R file, but that didn;t work.

Comment: How are you creating the gradients for the buttons? Is it an Image (Drawable) or a shape XML?

Comment: Its a PNG in another library, it looks like the black lines for path 9 are being drawn.